# Move the "Have you considered..." text to the right

Tags: bug, design, profile-page

I was looking over my Questions page, and found the "Have you considered accepting an answer or starting a bounty" message.

However, the text was on **the left** of the page - making it look very out of place.

If it were moved to the right, the votes/answer(s)/views count of the question wouldn't look so out of place (then, the UI would look more consistent).

[image: Picture of request]

Comment: This is actually a bug. That line is supposed to be centered text that spans the entire width *above* the question it's referencing, not pushed off to to the left or right. I think design changes just broke the display.

Comment: Yeah, that's not where that notice usually goes.